# Trouble running the command "Pod install"

Tags: ios, react-native, macos, cocoapods

I've been trying to run pod install on my react native app. I've tried close to every solution on here and I've had no luck, I keep getting the 2 errors:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
And
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located

I've tried reinstalling cocoapods, reinstalling xcode, moving the folder to a different location, and all of that has not worked.

Comment: Maybe it help when you set the command line tools in Xcode -> settings